# Are gutenberg blocks ideally supposed to look the same in both back-end and front-end?

Tags: block-editor

This appears to be the case with built in blocks at the moment. If you use them with default Twenty Nineteen theme you get the same look in both backend and frontend

When building custom theme, should we make sure blocks are identical in both cases? It seems that this requires loading the same CSS frameworks and JS in back-end and front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, yes. Blocks are supposed to be WYSIWYG. See the [Editor Styles section](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/themes/theme-support/#editor-styles) of the Gutenberg Handbook for how to load theme styles in the editor.

You need to add an editor stylesheet with `add_editor_style()`, the same way you did with the previous editor, but to support the block editor you need to declare theme support for editor styles:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
```